# How to use a command as path in 'includegraphics'?

Tags: macros, graphics

I want to include a graphic by using `\includegraphics{\mycommand}` but it doesn't work. The path to the picture will be a combination of text written in `.txt` files. This is my code:

```
\usepackage{german}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
% read in the files  
\def\textx{\input{x.txt}} %com  
\def\texty{\input{y.txt}} %bin  
\def\textz{\input{z.txt}} %ed   
\def\textp{\input{p.txt}} %.png  
% delete spaces etc.  
\newcommand{\textxx}{\unskip \textx \ignorespaces}  
\newcommand{\textyy}{\unskip \texty \ignorespaces}  
\newcommand{\textzz}{\unskip \textz \ignorespaces}  
\newcommand{\textpp}{\unskip \textp \ignorespaces}  
\textxx\textyy\textzz\textpp %combined.png  
%combine them  
\newcommand{\textv}{\textxx\textyy\textzz\textpp}  
\textv %output: combined.png  
\includegraphics{\textv} % Error: undefined control sequence
```

Comment: Impossible to see why you should get an undefined csname error from that fragment, please post an example that people can run to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: '\includegraphics{combined.png}' works fine. the command '\textv' puts out "combined.png". putting the name together works fine, i guess that 'includegrahpics' can't handle commands ?!

Comment: `\includegraphics{\textv}` already appears in your fragment, but you don't say what error you get and the code fragment isn't that useful as we can't run it.  However it is clear that your command will not expand to a filename, your commands at best expand to `\includegraphics{\unskip com\ignorespaces\unskip xxx\ignorespaces....}` and that does not work, even if you enter it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example in the question reveals quite some show stoppers:

- Package `graphics` needs to know the file name extension and calls LaTeX's `\filename@parse` to split the path specification. `\filename@parse` expands the first token once. Thus it is possible to put the starting path in a macro. But after the expansion step, further macros or nested macros are not expanded. They will break the file name parser, if they hide important path syntax elements. Nested macros can be avoided by expanding them by defining a macro with `\edef` and then passing the macro with the expanded path to `\includegraphics`.
- `\unskip` and `\ignorespaces` are unexpandable tokens, they will appear as path component. Check out package `trimspaces` or similar packages to strip spaces at the begin and end from a string.
- Also LaTeX's `\input` is not expandable. Even the primitive version `\@@input` is quite tricky to use:

  - Line ends cause unwanted spaces, they can be suppressed by `\endlinechar=-1`.
  - The file end causes an error in an expandable context, there are some tricks to avoid the error, e.g., `\everyeof{\noexpand}` with e-TeX.

  Package `catchfile` provides means to put files into macros.

If you want to use `\includegraphics{\imagepath}`, then you can inspect `\imagepath`:

```
\typeout{[meaning of \string\imagepath: \meaning\imagepath]}
```

will print the following to the console and log output, assuming `\imagepath` contains `x/y/z.png`:

```
[meaning of \imagepath: macro:->x/y/z.png]
```

The shown path should be free of TeX commands or unwanted spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I see what the problem is now. The string i produce is correct, but LaTeX still handles it as a command. Is it possible to save the pure string as a variable? such as: `string=\command1\command2`

Comment: @user4791982 The typeset output of a TeX macro is quite different from a plain string, needed as file name. Take care that each macro, which contains fragments of the file name does not contain any other macros, especially commands, which do not vanish, when expanded.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek when you say "Nested macros can be avoided by using `\etex`" do you mean `\edef`?

Comment: @Marijn Thanks. I have rephrased it to make it clearer hopefully.