# Can't include file with \includegraphics using ifthen

Tags: xetex, texlive, documentclass-writing, includegraphics

I am using TexLive and TexStudio as a compiler. I created a custom class in order to produce tests. In that class file there is an option for the color output so I can choose for example to use blue color if I want to upload the test in the internet and black if I want to print it.

As we can see in the following `test.cls` class file the `ifthen` package is loaded and reads the option I want to give.
If the option inside the `documentclass` is `internet` then the main color of the document is red and if I use the option `print` then the color is set to black.

**test.cls**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[29/7/2019 Test]
\DeclareOption{print}{\newcommand{\coloroutput}{print}}
\DeclareOption{internet}{\newcommand{\coloroutput}{internet}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{sectsty}
\RequirePackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\sectionfont{\centering}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\coloroutput}{internet}}
{\def\Col{red}
\def\image{Test.eps}}
{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\coloroutput}{print}}
{\def\Col{black}
\def\image{Test1.eps}}
{}


\newcommand{\titleStart}[3]{
\begin{center}
{\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{C:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/test/\image}
\end{figure}}\vspace{-5mm}
\rule{14.7cm}{.1mm}\\
\vspace{3mm}
{\bf {\Large Test}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
{\Large\bf\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\end{center}
\section*{{\huge \textcolor{\Col}{#2}}}
\vspace{-1mm}
\begin{center}
{\large\bf{\MakeUppercase{Test type: #3}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}}
```

At the top of the document an image is supposed to be loaded, which is red when the `internet` option is on and black for the `print` option. These images are located in the following directory `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\local\test` named Test.eps and Test1.eps respectively. The `ifthen` command reads the `documentclass` option and imports the red `Test.eps` file for the internet or the black `Test1.eps` for printing, using the `\image` command.

That's where the error show up. I get the error `File C:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/test/Test.eps' not found. \titleStart{Mathematics}{Algebra}{X}`

Before I switch to `Texlive` I used `MikTex` and the class was working fine producing the desired output. Now the only way to avoid the error is to specify the exact name of the file I want to use inside the `\includegraphics` command inplace of `\image`

I quote the `MWE` and the the two different type of exams I want to use.

```
\documentclass[print]{test}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\let\hbar\relax
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0,BoldFont={Times New Roman Bold}]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\titleStart{Mathematics}{Algebra}{X}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `\bf` has been deprecated since 1993. Why `figure`? There's nothing that imposes `\includegraphics` to appear in a `figure` environment, which is actually wrong in the context you're in, because it defines a floating object, while you want the picture *exactly there*. Finally, `xunicode` is no longer recommended with `fontspec`.

Comment: @egreg That's true. I used an old code which needs improvements.Either way the errors shows up even without these commands.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that `titlesec` and `sectsty` don't go along. About the problem with the path: are you sure you need it?

Comment: Why is that? In thw specific folder I have an image I use for my tests. How can I include it in all my documents without the path?Is there another way?

Comment: Things below `texmf-local/tex` are automatically found, with a well set up TeX Live.

Comment: I think I set up it well because if I replace the `\image` command inside `\includegraphics` with the name of the image : Test.eps then the image is found and shows up in the document.

Comment: Why are you adding the complete path? \includegraphics{\image} should work fine, if the images can be found with kpathsea.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't know how to do that. First time I hear about it. Is it useful?

Comment: that's the standard way tex finds its files, it can find article.cls so why shouldn't it be able to find an eps?

Comment: If I dont use the ifthen command and just replace `\image` with the name of the file then it can find it. If I use the `ifthen` command it produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [How to use a command as path in 'includegraphics'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240150/how-to-use-a-command-as-path-in-includegraphics) the `\includegraphics` command has problems parsing file names that consist of multiple elements. The solution is also given in that post, although a bit hidden. The idea is to compose a fully expanded path+filename string and use that as argument.

Code:

```
\def\image{yourimage.eps}
\edef\imagepath{/path/to/your/file/\image} % note the \edef, i.e., expanded def
\includegraphics{\imagepath}
```

Alternatively, as noted in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493974/, using the `grffile` package also works.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document}
\def\image{yourimage.eps}
\includegraphics{/path/to/your/file/\image}
\end{document}
```